# Jquery: how to know which element was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html code with 5 divs. They all have the same class, and different IDs.
Then, within javascript I have this:

```
$(".pics").click(function() {
alert("hey!");
});
```

where .pics is the name of the class of all the divs. The idea is that when I click on any of them, a certain script should be triggered, but I also want to know which one of the divs was clicked upon.

How do you go about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your  *ids* are like this:

`<div class="pics" id ="pic1">...</div>`

`<div class="pics" id ="pic2">...</div>`

`<div class="pics" id ="pic3">...</div>`

`<div class="pics" id ="pic4">...</div>`

`<div class="pics" id ="pic5">...</div>`

Then in your javascript:

```
$(".pics").click(function() {
alert("You are clicking "+$(this).attr('id'));
});
```

And you should see something like this:

```
You are clicking pic1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".pics").click(function() {
    alert("hey!" + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information from the target of the click event, as shown [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

```
$(".pics").click( function (e) {
    var clickedElement = e.target;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to that element.

```
$(".pics").click(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    alert(this.id);
});
```